# React testing with Hooks not working on State Update

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write a test case for a functional component which uses hooks for state update and gets data from a mock promise call.

// Functional Component

```
const MockPage = () => {
  const [mockData, setMockData] = React.useState<IMock[]>([]);
  const mockService = new mockService();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    mockService.getMockData().then((res) => {
      setMockData(res);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <MockTable mocktData={mockData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the test case that I have written which **PASSES** :

```
 it('renders without crashing', () => {
        mount(<MockPage />);
    });
```

Here are the test cases that I have written which **FAILS** :

```
 it('renders without crashing', () => {
       const wrapper =  mount(<MockPage />);
        expect(wrapper.is(MountTable)).toBeDefined();
    });



it('renders without crashing', () => {
           const wrapper =  mount(<MockPage />);
            expect(wrapper.find(MountTable).prop('mockData').toHaveLenght(2);
        }); // assusming the mockData has 2 objects in an array
```

What is the mistake(s) am committing here? Is there something am missing?

Note: I tried doing with act() too , but was not successful.

Comment: You could use debug to see what's actually getting rendered: `console.log('wrapper', wrapper.debug());` Also on the last test you're missing a parenthesis before `.toHaveLenght(2)`.

Comment: @Clarity I did that but it says an empty Renderer object

Answer (score 1):

Your data fetching happens asynchronously, so you need to wait for the promise to resolve before checking your data.

At a minimum (although this won’t always work when you have multiple promises), you can do this:

```
const wrapper = mount(<MockPage />);

return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  expect(...).toBe(true);
});
```

There’s a great library called `wait-for-expect` that can also help when `return Promise.resolve().then(...)` isn’t enough:

```
import waitForExpect from `wait-for-expect`;

const wrapper = mount(<MockPage />);

return waitForExpect(() => {
  expect(...).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: It fails with the following error  expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

Comment: That’s not enough information to help debug this. What is received/expected? If those are objects or arrays you will need to use `toEqual ` instead of `toBe `. You can use your `toHaveLength ` check if that’s simpler.